# python gnupg.GPG no such file or directory

Tags: python, gnupg

I'm trying to verify a file signature, however when creating my gnupg object using

```
gpg = gnugp.GPG(gnupghome='/Users/myname/.gnupg')
```

However I keep getting a no such file or directory error. I've also tried different paths for the home, as well as not including a path and letting it use the default, all to no avail.

Comment: Does the directory exist?

Comment: Yes, although according to the documentation (specifically [here](https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#getting-started)) that shouldn't matter.

Comment: What's the output of: `gpg = gnugp.GPG(gnupghome="/Users/myname/.gnupg", verbose=True)`?  Ideally you want it to end up something like this: `gpg --status-fd 2 --no-tty --homedir /Users/myname/.gnupg --no-default-keyring --keyring /Users/myname/.gnupg/pubring.gpg --secret-keyring /Users/myname/.gnupg/secring.gpg --version`

Answer (score 1):

Some of the functions do not need anything beyond the GPG home directory (i.e. ~/.gnupg) specified, but others require a little more than that.  Especially if you're manipulating keyrings.

I got around this by making a config.py file in the same directory as my other scripts which contains this:

```
homedir = "/Users/username"
gpg_home = homedir+"/.gnupg"
gpg_homeshort = "~/.gnupg" # optional
pub_ring = gpg_home+"/pubring.gpg"
sec_ring = gpg_home+"/secring.gpg"
pring = []
sring = []
pring.append(pub_ring)
sring.append(sec_ring)
```

That's for OS X, for Linux, BSD and other UNIXes change the first line to:

```
homedir = "/home/username"
```

For scripts with basic encryption and decryption, this should work:

```
import gnupg
from config import *
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home)
```

With the verbose parameter this results in:

```
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home, verbose=True)
gpg --status-fd 2 --no-tty --homedir /Users/username/.gnupg --version
>>>
```

The shorter form results in:

```
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_homeshort, verbose=True)
gpg --status-fd 2 --no-tty --homedir '~/.gnupg' --version
>>>
```

For scripts which search through the default keyrings, this should work:

```
import gnupg
from config import *
gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home, keyring=pring, secret_keyring=sring)
gpg.encoding = "latin-1"
pkeys = gpg.list_keys(False)
skeys = gpg.list_keys(True)
```

Note the change of character encoding, this is to prevent errors when reading some keyrings which may contain strange keys (which may or may not break the scripts if you leave it as "UTF-8").  This will result in pkeys and skeys being created as lists with each entry containing a dict for each key in the keyring.

The verbose form results in:

```
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home, keyring=pring, secret_keyring=sring, verbose=True)
gpg --status-fd 2 --no-tty --homedir /Users/username/.gnupg --no-default-keyring --keyring /Users/username/.gnupg/pubring.gpg --secret-keyring /Users/username/.gnupg/secring.gpg --version
>>>
```

The short form results in:

```
>>> gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_homeshort, keyring=pring, verbose=True)
gpg --status-fd 2 --no-tty --homedir '~/.gnupg' --no-default-keyring --keyring /Users/username/.gnupg/pubring.gpg --version
>>>
```

It is quite possible to manipulate the paths to use alternative keyrings or possibly relative paths for a portable implementation.

Anyway, here's a nice and quick demonstration with the keyrings (assuming the same config file as above):

```
import gnupg
from config import *

gpg = gnupg.GPG(gnupghome=gpg_home, keyring=pring, secret_keyring=sring)
gpg.encoding = "latin-1"
pkeys = gpg.list_keys(False)
skeys = gpg.list_keys(True)

pnum = len(pkeys)
snum = len(skeys)

print("""
%s contains %d public keys
%s contains %d private keys
""" % (pub_ring, pnum, sec_ring, snum))
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue and found a solution to the problem. The problem is OSX specific and is being caused because the gpg binary itself is not found.

So, passing the full path to the binary as an argument solved the problem.

```
gpg = gnugp.GPG(gnupghome='/Users/myname/.gnupg', gpgbinary='/usr/local/bin/gpg')
```

Comment: I was hopeful that this would help me since I'm using OSX for this but the code snippet you suggested has a syntax error... "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" ... because you have a space in between ...me/.gnupg' and gpgbinary='/usr/loc ... is it supposed to be a comma in there? I tried it with a comma and it doesn't work.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the comma. Thanks for pointing it out. Furthermore, according to docs https://pythonhosted.org/python-gnupg/#getting-started arguments should be there (still). What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is quite old, but maybe someone will find this helpful. I had exactly the same problem and found another solution which turned out to be quite silly.

On the [Gnu Privacy Guard website](https://www.gnupg.org/) there are three versions available for download. If, by any chance, you are using a version which starts with the number 2 the actual program is called `gpg2` and `python-gnupg` won't see what it is looking for, hence the error.
Simply install the "classic version" (1.4.20 at this moment), e.g. if you are on macos: `brew install gnupg` and everything should be fine.